# Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm currently learning about generalized eigenvectors, and I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this problem correctly.

If I'm given a square matrix $A$ that has a generalized eigenvector of order k>1, the direction of this eigenvector $\vec{v}_k$ is uniquely determined. I think this is true, since the direction of regular eigenvectors are uniquely determined even though their length might not be. Secondly, I am wondering whether the span{$\vec{v}_k,\vec{v}_{k-1},...,\vec{v}_1$} is invariant under $A$? Thanks for any help

Comment: Directions of eigenvectors are only uniquely determined when the eigenvector has a geometric multiplicity of 1.  This is because a one dimensional space has only one direction. For a simple counterexample, consider the $2\times2$ identity matrix, which has eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized eigenvector of order $k>1$ of $A$ for the (generalized)eigenvalue $\lambda$  is a vector $v$ so that $(A- \lambda \cdot I)^k v = 0$ ( for $k=1$ we get the usual eigenvector). No, the direction of the eigenvector is not uniquely determined. For example, take $A$ so that $(A-I) e_1 = e_2$, $(A-I)e_2 = 0$ on a $2$-dimensional space. Then $e_2$ is an eigenvector, $e_1$ is a generalized eigenvector of order $2$, but then so is $e_2 + \mu e_1$, for all $\mu$.

As for the subspace, yes, it is invariant.

Comment: Ahh okay that is a good counter example. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

A Jordan block is defined with 0 and 1 along the superdiagonals:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&1\\0&0&\lambda\end{array}\right]$$

However we can of course with linear combinations (row operations) build
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\lambda&x&y\\0&\lambda&z\\0&0&\lambda\end{array}\right], \text{   for any   } x,y,z$$

This would still have the same block structure so the vectors corresponding to the columns would still be generalized eigenvectors. But for the particular vectors corresponding to the JNF we require 1 and 0 in the places we usually do, then the only freedom is the order between Jordan blocks along the diagonal.